# What is the advantage of this javascript module pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js

So I have been writing a backbone application for some time now, and my modules are generally structured like so:

```
var AppName = AppName || {};

AppName.Module = {};

AppName.Module.View = Backbone.View.extend({...});
AppName.Module.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({...});
```

But I recently stumbled upon this module pattern:

```
var AppName = AppName || {};

AppName.Module = (function() {
    var View = Backbone.View.extend({...});
    var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({...});

    return {
        View: View,
        Model: Model
    }
})();
```

In the second pattern, you have the ability to define "private" methods that will only be accessible from the Module scope, but apart from that it only seems to me that it is generally a harder to test pattern. Can someone explain to me why some javascript programmers favor the second approach as an inherently better pattern?

Comment: *"why the second approach is a inherently better pattern?"* Looks like you made up your mind already, and you provided a reason for this opinion, also.

Comment: I mean that i have seen blogposts about this describing it as a better pattern, but I do not see why. I edited the post for clarity

Comment: Well, yes, because of the ability to use "private" local variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you can use private variables. For example, we can use the pattern to define `bob` and force the code to ue the `setName` function to change his name (i.e. you can't change the value by accessing it directly:

```
var bob = (function(){
  var name = "Bob";

  return {
    setName: function(newName){
      name = newName;
    },
    getName: function(){
      return name;
    }
  }
}());

console.log(bob.getName()); // "Bob"
console.log(bob.name); // undefined
bob.setName("Bobby");
console.log(bob.getName()); // "Bobby"
```

By executing the function definition immediately, you get a new scope you can use to "hide" itnernal variables using a closure.